# How flexible is "a dozen"?

Tags: word-usage, measuring-units

How flexible is the measurement "a dozen"?

If there are nine hundred and ninety-nine thousand people at a rally it is acceptable to say one million people attended, but if eleven people are arrested is it acceptable to round up to a dozen?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Dozen* is quite flexible when it is pluralized. While *hundreds* sounds natural, you don't often hear about there being *tens* of something. Saying there were *dozens* of something fills this void without implying an exact multiple of 12.

Comment: I agree with @Robusto's answer in terms of a single dozen being very specific, but I also agree with you with regards to a large number which might be called more generally, "dozens" of something. The two answers together, I think, fully answer the question.

Comment: I always figured the plural kinda lets you off the hook on "dozens". After all, 30 is 2.5 dozens.

Answer (score 25):

A dozen is a very specific measurement. It means twelve. If you have 11 items you can't call that a dozen, you'd have to say "around a dozen" or "about a dozen"; if you have 13 items you can say the same, or just call it a "[baker's dozen](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/65121/5822)."

Twelve is a small enough number that you don't really need much rounding.

Comment: Similarly "roughly a dozen", "nearly a dozen", and the less formal "a dozen or so" and "something like a dozen". It can be used without qualification in hyperbole: "I've got a dozen good reasons you shouldn't move to Ohio!"

Comment: +1 for answer and @Matthew Frederick, great comment to complete it.

Comment: But equally, a million is also a very specific measurement, and that is used more loosely.

Comment: @mx: But when people use the term "a million" they seldom mean exactly 1,000,000. I can give you a million reasons why this is true.

Comment: +1 If you say a dozen, and you're out by one, your error is at least 8.3%. But you say a million and you're out by one, your error is only 0.0001% (or more meaningfully, one part per million)