# A word like "hundreds" but for multiples of 10

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use “tens of” and “hundreds of”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16356/how-to-use-tens-of-and-hundreds-of)

Take this example:

> Hundreds of pieces were used to create it.

What if the amount were something like 20 or 30? What would the equivalent sentence be that would sound natural?

Comment: Hundred : Hundreds :: Ten : Tens.

Comment: I know this is not correct English but I like the sound of "deceds", as in, "There were deceds and deceds of them..."

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I confess, my first thought was "dozens". While "tens" is probably more accurate, it doesn't feel as comfortable to say (to me, anyway).

Comment: Most of the time I see it used ironically.

Comment: Actually, you're right.  If it's supposed to sound natural, and it doesn't have to be exactly precise (24 instead of 20 or 30, etc), *dozens* fits the bill perfectly.  *Hundreds* doesn't have to refer to even multiples of 100 (as in 300, 400, etc); people use it for amounts such as 472.  In the same way, if you wanted to generally describe, say, 52 objects, *dozens* would be better than *tens*.

Comment: Agree, would rarely say tens though I would sometimes. Would often use dozens. Also "scores" for multiples of 20 is very common.

Comment: Related: [How flexible is "a dozen"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/28034/10041)

Answer (score 27):

The equivalent sentence would be

> **Tens** of pieces were used to create it.

Comment: Doesn't this sound weird though?

Comment: Sounds fine to me.

Comment: Isn't it also tens of thousands? So its not weird at all.

Answer (score 4):

Scores are 20s. (I don't have a good answer for 30s.)

Comment: What if you wanted to specify any number that is a multiple of 10?

Answer (score 3):

"Dozens of".

You can use http://translate.google.cn/ for the answer.

Comment: Eh... Dozens are multiples of 12, not 10, I suppose. Aren't they?

Comment: @FractalizeR: Maybe mathematically, and maybe at the bakery, but not conversationally.  _"I saw dozens of pidgeons at the park"_ would imply the speaker saw as few as 25, or as many as 100 or so.  Not in my wildest dreams would I assume the speaker had counted the pidgeons, and only used the word _dozens_ because the total number happened to be an exact multiple of 12.

Answer (score 2):

"Lots of pieces were used to create it."

While this may not be particularly ideal, nobody has added an ambiguous answer yet, which can be useful sometimes.