# The origin of the term "Baker's Dozen"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, idioms

There's a "[hot question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/65093/5822)" at the moment about the use of the apostrophe in the phrase *Baker's Dozen*, and it got me to wondering: where did this phrase originate?

Did bakers really offer 13 in a *dozen*? Is it a joke about bakers being bad at maths? If bakers did offer 13 in a *dozen*, then why did they start doing it?

Comment: I thought the thirteenth one was for the baker.

Comment: In N.Y.C. it's not uncommon to get 13 bagels when you buy a dozen, either routinely or as a special promotion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you checked [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dozen)?

> The oldest known source, but questionable explanation for the expression "baker's dozen" dates to the 13th century [...]. Bakers who were found to have shortchanged customers (some variations say that they would sell hollow bread) could be subject to severe punishment. To guard against the punishment of losing a hand to an axe, a baker would give 13 for the price of 12, to be certain of not being known as a cheat. [...]

Comment: It's not just bakers, and it's not just a dozen. See Wikipedia on [lagniappe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagniappe), which also has a fascinating etymology. I don't think the custom needs an elaborate explanation.

Comment: @PeterShor Oh wow, I love that word, lagniappe! It *does* have a wonderful etymology! I first heard it when I was reading a travel guide for visitors to New Orleans and Louisiana in general. I agree with you, by the way. A baker's dozen, lagniappe, a "bonus round": All are forms of "x+1 for the price of x". It isn't even necessarily "plus one", just "something extra".

Comment: If you are talking about the 13th century or even the 16th then the packing of items on a tray or sheet is an anachronism. In these time and much later bread was baked on the oven floor and set with a peel. I doubt if the technology for steel trays was developed until the 18 century at the earliest.

Comment: @PeterShor That's only one possible explanation. It may have had literally nothing to do with bakers giving things away for free.

Comment: It seems pretty well documented that bakers gave away stuff for free. See [this website](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/Bakers%20dozen.html).

Comment: Lagniappe implies a businessman trying to exceed a customer's expectations. That link seems to suggest it was done entirely to make sure that they weren't fined to selling bread that was too light. I suppose it's similar, though.

Comment: I always thought it simply if one of the twelve was burnt or something, then the thirteenth could replace it, and the customer would get the 12 he asked for, and not have to wait for the baker to bake another if one did burn?

Comment: Like @PurplePilot said, the geometrical explanation is stuff and nonsense: not all baked items are round, and they didn't use rectangular baking pans until many centuries *after* the term 'baker's dozen' was first used.

Comment: And in fact the balderdash explanation has since been removed from Wikipedia, leaving just the accepted (although also doubtful) shortchanging explanation.

Comment: Following the deletion on Wikipedia, I have removed the speculative explanation on our site as well. I see no other option short of deleting the answer wholesale.

Comment: @Marthaª -- what is doubtful about the shortchanging explanation?  It's pretty routine to slightly over-fulfill orders (and to give grace periods in the sale of timed services) in situations where the marginal cost of the goods is very low compared to the value of reputation and the difficulty of acquiring customers.

Comment: @Malvolio: the whole "they added an extra loaf as insurance against getting their hand cut off" premise sets off all my urban legend detectors, because it sounds like typical middle-ages-bashing ("Look how cruel and nasty they were! And they used a lot of spices to hide the taste of spoiled meat!" [1. Spices were several order of magnitude more expensive than meat, and 2. Spoiled meat would have made them just as physically ill as it would make us, no matter how the well the taste was disguised.])

Comment: I loved that mathematical answer. Oh well.

Comment: I've removed the commentary from this answer as it doesn't really belong in the answer itself.

Comment: Incidentally, the concept that Malvolio correctly points out above is one of the first instances of "trademark" in history.

Answer (score 8):

As ‘Brewer’s Dictionary of Phrase and Fable’ explains:

> In earlier times when a heavy penalty was inflicted for short weight,
>   bakers used to give a surplus number of loaves, called the *in-bread*,
>   to avoid all risk of incurring a fine. The 13th was the *vantage loaf*.

Comment: Oh, I like that too: The "vantage loaf". It reminds me of Yahrzeit (Yarhzeit? no, Yahrzeit, I think) candles, though tangentially. They must have sufficient wax to burn continuously for a full 24 hours. I've noticed that they usually are good for at least 26, even 30  hours though, as I have used them during power outages, not just for commemoration of the dead.

Comment: I suppose it should be spelt "Jahrzeit"

Comment: "We picked up one excellent word — a word worth travelling to New Orleans to get; a nice limber, expressive, handy word — 'lagniappe'." -- Mark Twain

Answer (score 3):

On Oxford Dictionary we can read:

> *baker's dozen*: a group of thirteen (= one more than a dozen, which is
>   twelve)
>
> Origin.
>   late 16th century: from the former bakers' custom of adding an
>   extra loaf to a dozen sold, this constituting the retailer's profit.

More historical reasons are illustrated on Wikipedia with regard to "[Worshipful Company of Bakers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worshipful_Company_of_Bakers)":

> The Worshipful Company of Bakers is one
>   of the Livery Companies of the City of London. The Bakers' Guild is
>   known to have existed in the twelfth century. From the Corporation of
>   London, the Guild received the power to enforce regulations for
>   baking, known as the Assize of Bread and Ale. The violations included
>   selling short-weight bread and the addition of sand instead of flour.
>   (`So that they could avoid punishment for inadvertently selling a
>   short-weight bread, bakers added a thirteenth loaf to a dozen, giving
>   rise to the term baker's dozen.`) The Bread Assize remained in force
>   until 1863, when Parliament repealed it.

Answer (score 3):

I was always told this was the baker cooks 13 - 12 for the customer and one for himself. That way if the batch came out bad, he can easily find out and pitch it before it gets to the customer.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this differently.  From what I was taught, the *baker's dozen* resulted from compassion.

The extra item was added by the baker so the households slave/servant would be able to consume one of whatever was being purchased, while walking home with a bag full of food for their master/employer.